# How to add query string to end of the URL in WordPress Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin which is called WP My Plugin (renamed) and its added under WordPress admin **settings** menu.

Now, this plugin **URL** is look like this:

[image]

http://localhost/xxx/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wp-my-plugin

Now, I want to add query string to end of that URL. So final URL will be:

http://localhost/xxx/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wp-my-plugin&tab=general

Can you tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can add query string by using action.

**Add the below code in your current active theme functions.php file.**

*Before add the code make sure you have write the correct $submenu['options-general.php'][47][2] index. To check this please print_r($submenu); and replace with your key.*

```
add_action( 'admin_menu','add_custom_query_string');
function add_custom_query_string()
{
    global $submenu; 
    //print_r($submenu);die;
    $submenu['options-general.php'][47][2] = 'options-general.php?page=wp-my-plugin&tab=general';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I can't find the index 47 by print_r().

Comment: please search wp-my-plugin in your print_r data . In my case i found at index 47 under index option-general.php

Comment: I have used this to check `echo '<pre>';
  print_r($submenu['options-general.php']);
  echo '</pre>';` Its showing me up to 45 index that is privacy page

Comment: the hook should be on `admin_init` not `admin_menu`. Now it's index is 46 but I think thats not a proper solution.